# C# - Better way than watin to scrape PDF File from a domain using Javascript

Tags: c#, web, watin

I am currently building a little application based on watin that log in into a website and then start going through a serie of URL to download PDF files using Watin.

The website uses a lot of javascript to load  pdf in embedded HTML.

The program works fine for now but is very slow since watin doesn't handle downloads very efficiently ( It uses Firefox download system and type slowly filename before saving.

I would like to know if there is a better framework for Web Scraping that could provide the same support for Ajax sites but better / faster way to download files.

I've been all around the web and found about selenium, but it doesn't present itself as more efficient than watin concerning file downloading.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might well be better off finding out where/how on the source HTML page the link to PDF file exists.  Possibly you might be better off using HtmlAgilityPack, and scrape the page that way (though you'd have to forgo the javascript).  It might be easier to help if you let us know what site it is you are trying to scrape.

Comment: have you tried the [Chrome Driver for Selenum](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) ? In my experience it's faster than watin.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Google Chrome extension using these two APIs as the main engine:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html 
to know when and how to authenticate and when to start download and:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html
to start the download of the file.

Whatever is missing from these two APIs for you to achieve your goal, you can compensate with a custom content script - a javascript that is injected into the page that is opened by the extension - and for example hook into the jquery's .ready event to initialize scraping.

These will definitely be faster than Watin since writing for watin is a layer of abstraction more than talking to the browser directly.